# NRST and NOINIT issue - SRAM data retention

Tags: c++, embedded, linker-scripts

I'm working on the Upsilon Project (https://github.com/UpsilonNumworks/Upsilon) and I have some trouble to implement sram data retention after reset (using nrst pin).

I want to preserve the data on the staticStorageArea, so I did this:

```
extern "C" {
   extern char _bss_records_section_start;
}

static volatile uint32_t * staticStorageArea[sizeof(Storage)/sizeof(uint32_t)] __attribute__((section(".noinit"))) ;
```

And there is my linker script:

```
MEMORY {
  INTERNAL_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00200000, LENGTH = 64K
  SRAM (rw)  : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 256K - 0xfa20
  NOINIT (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000 + 256K - 0xfa20, LENGTH = 0xfa20
  EXTERNAL_FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x90000000, LENGTH = 8M
}

STACK_SIZE = 32K;
FIRST_EXTERNAL_FLASH_SECTOR_SIZE = 4K;

SECTIONS {
  .isr_vector_table ORIGIN(INTERNAL_FLASH) : {
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector_table))
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH

  .header : {
    KEEP(*(.header))
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH

  .text.internal_to_external : {
    ...
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH
    ...
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH


  .rodata.internal : {
    ...
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH

  .exam_mode_buffer ORIGIN(EXTERNAL_FLASH) : {
    ...
  } >EXTERNAL_FLASH

  /* External flash memory */
  .text.external : {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)
    *(.text.*)
  } >EXTERNAL_FLASH

  .rodata.external : {
    *(.rodata)
    *(.rodata.*)
  } >EXTERNAL_FLASH

  .init_array : {
    ...
  } >INTERNAL_FLASH

  .data : {
...
  } >SRAM AT> INTERNAL_FLASH

  .bss : {
    ...
  } >SRAM

  .heap : {
    ...
  } >SRAM

  .stack : {
    ...
  } >SRAM

  .noinit (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4) {
    _bss_records_section_start = .;
    KEEP(*(.noinit))
    KEEP(*(.noinit*))
    _bss_records_section_end = .;
  } >NOINIT

  /DISCARD/ : {
    ...
  }
}

NOCROSSREFS_TO(.text.external .text.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.rodata.external .text.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.text.external .rodata.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.rodata.external .rodata.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.text.external .isr_vector_table);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.rodata.external .isr_vector_table);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.text.external .header);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.rodata.external .header);

NOCROSSREFS_TO(.exam_mode_buffer .text.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.exam_mode_buffer .rodata.internal);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.exam_mode_buffer .isr_vector_table);
NOCROSSREFS_TO(.exam_mode_buffer .header);
```

I noticed that after every reset the data in the .noinit section is like corrupted, and I do not understand why... maybe I didn't understand correctly what nrst does in fact ? (on the website it's wrote that the power is "virtually disconnected")

Comment: The project you are working on is largely irrelevant.  What is relevant is what hardware  you are running on - the effect of NRST would be defined in the datasheet or technical reference for the part in question.

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted".  The area will contain random/non-deterministic values unless explicitly assigned in your code.  What is `Storage` and thus `sizeof(Storage)`?  The type of `staticStorageArea[]` looks wrong.  It is an array of pointers, so it is not clear why it contains `sizeof(Storage)/sizeof(uint32_t)` such pointers - that does not make much sense semantically.

Comment: @Clifford Hi , thanks for your reply ! So I'm running on a STM32F412VGT6 and the Storage is where the records are menaged. The staticStorageArea is a buffer where the class instance is saved in order to have the location in memory of the data (for the dfu mode). I specify the project to make easiest the access to the code, I mean, to look through the linkers scripts and the storage class files. If you want, for more clarity, I can comment the direct links to the files concerned ^^

Comment: And I also research the key word nrst in the mcu documentation, and didn't find anything clear about what happen to the sram. By corrupted, I mean there are random values instead of the previous data.